# syncing custom horizontal scrollbar's scroll to datagridview's scroll

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have a datagridviews and two custom scrollbars - one vertical and one horizontal scrollbar.

I am resizing the scrollbars when datagridview is populated

```
scrollBarEx1.Maximum = dataGridView1.RowCount;
scrollBarEx3.Maximum = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
```

This is the scroll event for datagridview1

```
private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
            {
                scrollBarEx1.Value = e.NewValue;
            }
            else if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
            {
                scrollBarEx3.Value = e.NewValue;
            }
        }
```

And here under is the code for scroll event for both scrollbars

```
private void scrollBarEx1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex].Height = e.NewValue;
}

private void scrollBarEx3_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex].Width = e.NewValue;
        }
```

However only vertical scroll is working. Horizontal scroll does scroll, but the grid does not scroll with it. Help please.

Comment: What are the values for *LargeChange* and *SmallChange* for both scrollbars?

Comment: `LargeChange = 10` and `SmallChange = 1` for both scrollbars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a custom scroll you always set the values of *maximum, largechange and small change* as follows:

> Horizontal Scroll
>
> Maximum = total width
> LargeChange = control width
> SmallChange = 10% of total width, in this case the width of first column
>
> Vertical Scroll
>
> Maximum = total height
> LargeChange = control height
> SmallChange = 10% of total height, in this case the height of first row

So for horizontal:

```
//set these values probably at form load event
int totalwidth = dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth + 1;
         
for( int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++ ) {
    totalwidth += dataGridView1.Columns[ i ].Width;
}

hScrollBar1.Maximum = totalwidth;
hScrollBar1.LargeChange = dataGridView1.Width;
hScrollBar1.SmallChange= dataGridView1.Columns[ 0 ].Width;
```

and

```
private void dataGridView1_Scroll( object sender, ScrollEventArgs e ) {
    if( e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll ) {
        hScrollBar1.Value = e.NewValue;
    }
}

private void hScrollBar1_Scroll( object sender, ScrollEventArgs e ) {
    dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset = e.NewValue;
}
```

**EDIT**

for verticall scroll in *DataGridView* you can't scroll by pixels but by rows only. So

> Vertical Scroll
>
> Maximum = total number of rows
> LargeChange = number of visible rows, even a small part counts
> SmallChange = 1

So for vertical

```
vScrollBar1.Maximum = dataGridView1.RowCount;
vScrollBar1.LargeChange = dataGridView1.DisplayedRowCount(true);
vScrollBar1.SmallChange = 1;
```

and

```
private void dataGridView1_Scroll( object sender, ScrollEventArgs e ) {
    if( e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll ) {
        vScrollBar1.Value = e.NewValue;
    }
}

private void vScrollBar1_Scroll( object sender, ScrollEventArgs e ) {  
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = e.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: `int totalwidthgrid1 = dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                totalwidthgrid1 += dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width;
            }

            scrollBarEx3.Maximum = totalwidthgrid1;
            scrollBarEx3.LargeChange = dataGridView1.Width;
            scrollBarEx3.SmallChange = dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width;`

Comment: `int totalheightgrid1 = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                totalheightgrid1 += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Height;
            }

            scrollBarEx1.Maximum = totalheightgrid1;
            scrollBarEx1.LargeChange = dataGridView1.Height;
            scrollBarEx1.SmallChange = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height;`

The previous comment has code for width and this one is for height.

Comment: Also this is not working.

`private void scrollBarEx1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.VerticalScrollingOffset = e.NewValue;
        }`

It has a squiggly line under `dataGridView1.VerticalScrollingOffset = e.NewValue;` but does not state anything else in particular.

However this,
`private void scrollBarEx3_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset = e.NewValue;
        }`
works just fine.

Comment: @fasih Yes indeed. I didn't know that. That is cause you can scroll by rows and not by pixels. See edit

Comment: Yes, so wouldn't

`//dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = e.NewValue;
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex].Height = e.NewValue;`

change too accordingly? Because grid is scrolling but is not synced. Grid is scrolled to end while the scrollbar has moved just a bit. The default scrollbar is working as expected.

Comment: Oh sorry, looks like you have edited it. Let me check it out.

Comment: Thank you for lending a helping hand. Does work like a charm.